# Join lines from pipe

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Bash has the [paste command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/paste.html), which can combine lines from standard input

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; } | paste -s -d ,
foo,bar,baz
```

Given this PowerShell command

```
& { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; }
```

I would like to pipe to something that will create the same output. I tried with
Write-Host but the Separator option was ignored

```r
PS > & { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; } | write-host -NoNewline -Separator ','
foobarbaz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find a Powershell cmdlet that will do exactly what you want, you can always roll your own:

```
function paste ($separator = ',') {$($input) -join $separator}
& { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; } | paste

foo,bar,baz
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the `-join` operator, but you'd have to use it like this:

```
(& { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; }) -join ","
```

You're not really piping the output anywhere. Just collecting the result first then joining.

You could also do it with `ForEach-Object`, if you really want to pipe it, but it's a little verbose:

```
& { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; } | foreach -Begin { $res = @() } { $res += $_ } -End { $res -join "," }
```

Comment: here is a slightly more simplified use of -join `@( echo foo; echo bar; echo baz ) -join ","`

Comment: @kevmar I'm assuming that in a real case the OP is calling a function or script. The example is just a way to have output to the pipeline. Applying my suggestion to a more realistic case would look something like `(invoke-myfunction -parameter 1) -join ","`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write-Host (& { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; }) -Separator ","
```

or more explicitly:

```
[string[]]$myvariable = (& { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; })
Write-Host $myvariable -Separator ","
```